# Share a hard drive for backing up using Mac TimeMachine and Ubuntu System Backups

Tags: ubuntu, backup, hard-drive, time-machine, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro using Time Machine for whole system backup and a Ubuntu installed on another Macbook Pro (not dual boot) using default system backup.  I have a 4TB SATA hard drive partitioned into four partitions each of which is of 1TB.  I'd like to backup computer #1 on partition #1 and computer #2 on partition #2.  The hard drive is connected to each computer with a Thermaltake BlacX eSATA USB Docking Station.  How should I need to format the two partitions differently?  Is there any potential issues with this plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time Machine only backs up to HFS+ partitions, so you'll need use the Apple Disk Utility to format the partition for Time Machine.

For Linux, you can use any filesystem your OS can write to, but I'd personally use ext3 or ext4. You can format this using GParted, just remember to only touch the Linux partition.

Comment: So it is safe to have partitions with different formats?

Comment: Indeed it is :)